# Software centre (in 16.10) won't recognise my Ubuntu One password

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm trying to install both VLC and Krita via the software centre and it's requiring me to create an Ubuntu One account, which I did; only trouble is though, is that the password I created isn't being recognized by my system! Does anyone know how to sort this?

Comment: Software center should not force you to login to Ubuntu One account, if you want to download free stuff. Are you sure you are not being asked for root password?

Comment: As above, unless you're trying to install snap packages in which case Ubuntu SSO is needed and the Software Center still has a bug re: authentication. You're advised to install packages in terminal, at the moment.